# Random Numbers without ascending and descending orders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I have a problem with a method that generates numbers that do not repeat. Everything goes fine, but I would never want to get a result like:
1,2,3,4 or 4,3,2,1 . The idea is not to receive the numbers in ascending order or in descending order.

Below is the method implemented if someone can help me. Thank you!

```
public static List<int> GenerateNumbers(int mn, int mx)
{
    List<int> source = new List<int>();
    for (int i = mn; i <= mx; i++)
        source.Add(i);
    List<int> randomNumbers = new List<int>();
    while (source.Count != 0)
    {
        int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, source.Count - 1);
        randomNumbers.Add(source[randomIndex]);
        source.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
    }
    return randomNumbers;
}

public static bool IsSorted(List<int> arr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So are you getting random numbers in sequence, such as `1,2,3,4` with this code?

Comment: yes, that's what I sometimes get

Comment: Just shuffle the List after creating it. See the duplicate

Comment: this is very rare, but it happens

Comment: I did a checkup method but it does not work. I've modified the code above.

Comment: Your `IsSorted` function will not return the desired values in all cases. For example, the array `[2, 4, 1, 3]` will return `true` because 2 is less than 4.